# ¿Cómo reproducir un sonido en JAVA varias veces sin que sature la memoria? Utilizo la librería AudioStream

Tags: java, manejo-de-memoria, bucles

Primero que todo, no pido solución de ¿cómo reproducir? porque el sonido si se reproduce cuando corro el código.
Lo que pasa es que quiero que quede de fondo infinitamente hasta que finalice el programa pero no quiero que sature la memoria.
Esta es la clase del sonido que quiero reproducir...

```
package Clases;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class SonidoJuego extends Thread{
    Clip audio;
    InputStream ruta;


    @Override
    public void run(){

        try {
            ruta =getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Sonidos/SonidoJuego.wav");
            audio = AudioSystem.getClip();
            audio.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(ruta)) ;
            audio.start();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SonidoJuego.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SonidoJuego.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SonidoJuego.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }  
}




Y éste es el JFrame principal donde apenas corra, el sonido se debería reproducir infinitas veces, así lo llamo.

    public JFrame() {
        initComponents();
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        new Clases.SonidoGameOver().start();

        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es que se ejecute como un bucle? Que cuando acabe vuelva a empezar, ¿no? ¿Has probado a establecer la propiedad: loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY) ?

Comment: Gracias Javi, me sirvió. Saludos